# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, out-of-memory, helios, xtext

I have created an Xtext plugin in eclipse. Every time I launch it as an 'Eclipse Application' via the context menu, I get a few moments grace before the new Eclipse instance crashes. I switch back to the original instance and in the console window I see

```
Root exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I have looked back at some solutions in the forums but a lot relate to tomcat. Can someone give me a few suggestions as to how I could fix this? I am using Eclipse helios. My 'eclipse.ini' file looks like:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

The machine I am running eclipse on has just about 4GB of RAM

======================================================================

Update: I hope this is helpful to anyone who may have the same problem.
I followed the instructions [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=171988&start=0&S=404fe750f2e7196f4c1d669b0f5a5678) and tried setting the 
`-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` in my eclipse.ini file. This did not work. Eventually,
I had to uninstall java sdk (I was using the latest jdk1.6.0_26) and I installed
an older version (jdk1.6.0_20) from [here](http://java.sun.com/products/archive/j2se/6u20/index.html). I then set `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`
in my eclipse.ini and it now looks like the following:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.2.R36x_v20101222
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I hope this helps out someone in the same situation. This problem was happening 
when I'd launch my Xtext plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please add following to the vm parameters in the launch configuration (Run -> Run Configurations)

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

That should help.

Comment: what exactly it does when you set argument like

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Eclipse Helios build - 1415 (64 Bit). Adding it to the run configurations above didn't work for me. I had to go in and add it to the eclipse.ini file. Just appended it towards the end of the file and restarted eclipse and it works.